# Head section of the wordpress blog

Tags: css

I'd like to set a embedded mailchimp form to my website but can't since I can't find a head section for part of the code. Where could it be found or is it available only for upgraded versions?

Answer (score 0):

You can hook it in via your functions file:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_form_code' );

function add_form_code() {

echo 'Your Forms HTML Here';  

}
```